# Python: Can't understand why I get an infinite float in this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes

In the following code, if I update the price to 29.99, I get the correct value of 149.95. But using the original 19.99, I'm getting 99.94999999999999 instead.

I don't know what else details does this want to allow me to post, it's a simple question but I don't understand what's happening.

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, code, name, price, type):
        # Defining private attributes with double underscore
        self.__code = code
        self.__name = name
        self.__price = price
        self.__type = type

        # Confirmation message when creating a product
        print(f"Product '{name}' created successfully!")

    # Getter methods to retrieve attribute values
    def get_code(self):
        return self.__code

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    def get_type(self):
        return self.__type

    # Setter methods to set new values to attributes
    def set_code(self, code):
        self.__code = code

    def set_name(self, name):
        self.__name = name

    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    def set_type(self, type):
        self.__type = type

    # Method to calculate the total price based on the number of units
    def calculate_total(self, units):
        return self.get_price() * units
    
    # __str__ method to print product data
    def __str__(self):
        return f"\tCode: {self.get_code()}\n\tName: {self.get_name()}\n\tPrice: {self.get_price()}\n\tType: {self.get_type()}"

# Create some product objects
products = []
product1 = Product("1A123A", "Louis Vuitton Shirt", 19.99, "Apparel")
products.append(product1)
product2 = Product("2BTA25", "NIKE ZYZ Sneakers", 59.99, "Footwear")
products.append(product2)

# Access and modify attributes using getter and setter methods
# Display products and attributes
for i, product in enumerate(products, start=1):
    print(f"\nProduct {i}:\n{product}")

# Update attributes of product1 using setter methods
#print()
#product1.set_price(29.99)
#print(f"Price of {product1.get_name()} updated successfully to {product1.get_price()}.")
#product1.set_type("Clothing")
#print(f"Type of {product1.get_name()} updated successfully to {product1.get_type()}.")

# Print updated attributes
#for i, product in enumerate(products, start=1):
#    print(f"\nProduct {i}:\n{product}")

# Calculate the total price for a set of products
units = 5
total = product1.calculate_total(units)
print(f"\nTotal price for {units} units of {product1.get_name()}: {total}€")
```

Comment: You can adjust the display if you like `print(f"\nTotal price { (5 * 19.99):.2f}€")`